# How to toggle between two classes for each corresponding div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple carousels using the Slick Slider plugin on one page. I've managed to setup custom navigation for each carousel but I would like each navigation link to toggle between two classes when clicked.

I've managed to create a toggle between the two however it's applying the toggle to all carousels, not just the one with the navigation that's been clicked.

**Update:**
**I need the classes to only toggle when the carousel changes slide.**

I'm almost where I need to be but a little stuck and would appreciate any help finishing this off.

Here's the demo - http://jsfiddle.net/81t4pkfa/158/

HTML:

```
<link href="https://rawgit.com/kenwheeler/slick/master/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="test">
    <div class="option">
        <p>Test 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
        <p>Test 1 -</p>
    </div>
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li class="tab slide-0 active-slide">
        <a href="#">1. Slide 0</a>
      </li>
      <li class="tab slide-1 inactive-slide">
        <a href="#">1. Slide 1</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="test">
    <div class="option">
        <p>Test 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
        <p>Test 2 -</p>
    </div>
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li class="tab slide-0 active-slide">
        <a href="#">2. Slide 0</a>
      </li>
      <li class="tab slide-1 inactive-slide">
        <a href="#">2. Slide 1</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="test">
    <div class="prev_next"></div>
    <div class="option">
        <p>Test 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
        <p>Test 3 -</p>
    </div>
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li class="tab slide-0 active-slide">
        <a href="#">3. Slide 0</a>
      </li>
      <li class="tab slide-1 inactive-slide">
        <a href="#">3. Slide 1</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kenwheeler/slick/master/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
```

JS:

```
$('.test').each(function (idx, item) {
    var carouselId = "carousel" + idx;
    this.id = carouselId;
    $(this).slick({
        slide: "#" + carouselId +" .option",
        adaptiveHeight: true,
        autoplay: false,
        arrows: false,
        dots: true
    });
});

$(".tabs li a").click(function(){
  var slideIndex = $(this).parent().index();
  $(this).closest('.test').slick('slickGoTo', parseInt(slideIndex));
  $('.tab').toggleClass('inactive-slide active-slide');
});
```

Comment: add html mark up as well

Comment: that;s because you're using classes, use $(this) with toggleClass to get it what ya want :)

Comment: You need to use $(this).parents('.tab').toggleClass

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions, however, none seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really want do is to change tabs activity class not on click  but on slide change. You should keep only slide change trigger (`slickGoTo`) in your `.tab` on click event. There's a set of events in Slick Carousel that will tell you that the slide has (or is going to) change, e.g. `beforeChange`. That's what you should use to toggle activity.

Your code should look then like this:

```
$('.test').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
  if (currentSlide !== nextSlide) {
      $(this).find('.tab').toggleClass('inactive-slide active-slide');
  }
});

$(".tabs li a").click(function(){
  var slideIndex = $(this).parent().index();
  $(this).closest('.test').slick('slickGoTo', parseInt(slideIndex));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/norin89/81t4pkfa/161/

UPDATE:
Note that this gonna work only for 2 slides due to `.active-slide` / `.inactive-slide` classes toggling. So on slide change in current code all previously inactive tabs will be toggled to active. If you want only one active tab to get `.active-slide` class you might do something like this:

```
$('.test').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
      $(this).find('.tab').removeClass('active-slide').addClass('inactive-slide')
             .eq(nextSlide).toggleClass('active-slide inactive-slide');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/norin89/81t4pkfa/164/

Comment: That's perfect, thank you for explaining this to me.

Answer (score 2):

Change to this

```
 $(".tabs li a").click(function(){
      var slideIndex = $(this).parent().index();
      $(this).closest('.test').slick('slickGoTo', parseInt(slideIndex));
    $(this).parents('.tabs').find('.tab').toggleClass('inactive-slide active-slide');
    });
```

EDIT :

```
$(".tabs li a").click(function(){
  var slideIndex = $(this).parent().index();
  $(this).closest('.test').slick('slickGoTo', parseInt(slideIndex));
 $(this).parents('.tabs').find('.tab').removeClass('active-slide');
  $(this).parents('.tabs').find('.tab').addClass('inactive-slide');
  $(this).parent().addClass('active-slide');
$(this).parent().removeClass('inactive-slide'); 
});
```

Comment: you need to change from parent to parents that is it

Comment: @TejasVaishnav yes i updated with parents, it will also work

Comment: Thanks for your answer also, this is what I need however is there a way that I can stop the toggle happening if the user clicks on .tab twice? In other words the toggle only happens in relation to the slide changing. Does that makes sense?

Comment: Just FYI `closest()` would be better logically here, as it stops once it reaches the first match. `parents()` continues up the DOM to the `body`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you're toggling the class on all `.tabs` elements. Instead you need to traverse the DOM to call `toggleClass()` only on those which are contained within the same `.tabs` as the `a` which caused the `click` event. To do that you can use `closest()` and `find()`, like this:

```
$(".tabs li a").click(function(){
  var slideIndex = $(this).parent().index();
  $(this).closest('.test').slick('slickGoTo', parseInt(slideIndex));
  $(this).closest('.tabs').find('.tab').toggleClass('inactive-slide active-slide');
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/81t4pkfa/160/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is what I need however is there a way that I can stop the toggle happening if the user clicks on `.tab` twice? In other words the toggle only happens in relation to the slide changing. Hopefully that makes sense?

Comment: I'd suggest starting a new question about that, tagging your specific slider library in the question